# Audio Cuts Out, Replaced by Loud Hiss, from MSI Motherboard

Tags: audio, motherboard, troubleshooting, sound-card

I have a new [MSI z590 Torpedo motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-Z590-TORPEDO/Specification) on a (mostly) new [build](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/MnjyNP). Using the TOSLINK audio output, the sound will work normally for some time but suddenly and randomly the sound will cut out and a very loud hissing sound is output instead.

What can I do to make this audio output behave normally?

UPDATE 2021-05-04: after bringing the drivers and BIOS to their latest versions from the manufacturers, the problem is much more rare now. I can go many hours without it happening but this morning the audio hiss returned when I turned on my second monitor.

Comment: Can you test if it also does it over S/PDIF or even analog, to eliminate anything after the TOSLink connection?

Comment: Tested that too. It doesn't do this when using the other outputs.

Comment: This might be bad connection or interference on the motherboard.

Comment: @harrymc could you elaborate? Specifically what might be badly connected? Is there anything to be done to correct sporadic interference?

Comment: TOSLink & RCA S/PDIF ought to be using the same op amp, apart from the actual conversions to light vs 'leccy, so the issue could be in the actual optical converter… or at the other end, the receiver. Not sure how to diagnose that without another receiver for comparison &/or another light-pipe cable. If you've not got a spare to test, I'd be tempted to swap to RCA. I'm assuming the two outs are a 'signal-equivalent' sub-set of AES3.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the receiver because I have very recently used two different TOSLink connections to it without having this issue.

Comment: That would then likely make it somewhere between the final op amp & the light conversion. I really have no clue how to diagnose that, sorry. A fiver buys you a cheapo USB box with another TOSLink in it. That's going to be 'good enough' to squeeze interweb movie sound, or gaming, out of a PC to a 5.1 system. It's the kind of thing I do with consumer HTPC machines if I run out of audio routes.

Comment: This seems common with realtek alc4080 audio. Here are some related threads, in case they're helpful.

  - https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabyte/comments/mrsi0z/z590_alc4080_static_audio/
 
 - https://www.reddit.com/r/MSI_Gaming/comments/mkvedg/audio_suddenly_goes_to_static/

  - https://www.tenforums.com/sound-audio/176993-new-4080-usb-codec-z590-issues.html 

  - https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/bug-optical-audio-blasting-static.362096/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the msi z590 tomahawk and was having the exact same issue using my headset connected over spdif optical audio out. I would lose audio completely and then a really loud hiss like an old analog tv set to a channel with no signal. I updated my bios to the latest version since it mentioned "upgraded audio compatibility" in the patch notes and problem hasnt come back yet. I used the MSI Center app and it downloaded and installed the latest bios for me and the process was very simple.

Comment: What's the version number for the BIOS you upgraded to?

Comment: 7D08v21 is the latest one listed on msi's site that mentions the Improved Audio compatibility and I believe thats what msi center installed. before the audio would cut out after 10-20 minutes and I played all weekend for hours with no drop outs

Comment: I brought the BIOS and driver versions both up-to-date with the latest versions on the MSI site, and I've been able to go a whole day without any of the drop outs either. I'm hoping to be able to call it fixed after another day.

Comment: It definitely runs better now but the hissing did return, this time after I turned on one of my monitors. So it seems that the update helped a lot but didn't solve the issue completely.

Comment: MSI posted a firmware update to solve the issue on 6/9 and so far so good on my end

Comment: Thank you for saying so. I hadn't noticed. Gonna go try it out right now :)